# Delete row with condition

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have this dataframe:

```
id                 action     user            weight                 timestamp
830093             opt_in    56610               NaN  2017-01-29T23:03:35.000Z
830095           level_up    56610               NaN  2017-01-29T23:03:36.000Z
2312674     checkout_item    56610            239.99  2017-05-15T23:19:20.000Z
2313301     checkout_item    56610            239.99  2017-05-15T23:19:20.000Z
2315639          checkout    56610            239.99  2017-05-15T23:19:20.000Z
2316158       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-05-15T23:13:33.000Z
2402783       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-05-23T10:51:09.000Z
2438779       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-05-24T01:10:52.000Z
2530543       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-05-25T22:21:10.000Z
2573416       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-05-28T01:38:46.000Z
2679591       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-06-05T09:33:59.000Z
2813275   checkout_reject    56610               NaN  2017-06-15T04:29:02.000Z
2981829       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-06-26T16:40:56.000Z
3195018       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-07-11T09:11:35.000Z
3244062       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-07-14T17:46:04.000Z
3311904       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-07-20T00:50:08.000Z
3313849          checkout    56610            459.20  2017-07-20T09:17:12.000Z
3313852     checkout_item    56610            459.20  2017-07-20T09:17:12.000Z
3764903       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-08-18T10:24:23.000Z
3781360   checkout_update    56610            459.20  2017-08-19T07:10:25.000Z
3781363     checkout_item    56610            459.20  2017-08-19T07:10:25.000Z
3781366   checkout_accept    56610               NaN  2017-08-19T07:10:26.000Z
4095024       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-09-05T07:31:44.000Z
4557587       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-10-01T19:40:10.000Z
4652940       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-10-06T17:36:52.000Z
5455155     checkout_item    56611               NaN  2017-11-17T00:35:29.000Z
5455155   checkout_update    56611               NaN  2017-11-17T00:35:29.000Z
5455155   checkout_accept    56611               NaN  2017-11-17T00:35:41.000Z
5455155       daily_login    56611               NaN  2017-11-18T00:31:27.000Z
5455155       daily_login    56611               NaN  2017-11-19T00:37:19.000Z
5455155     checkout_item    56611            100.00  2017-11-19T00:35:29.000Z
5455155     checkout_item    56611            100.00  2017-11-17T00:35:29.000Z
5455155          checkout    56611            100.00  2017-11-17T00:35:29.000Z
5455155       daily_login    56610               NaN  2017-11-19T00:38:25.000Z
```

I want to use pandas to count checkout_item-s only which happened together with checkout

user: 56610  num_of_checkout_item:3

user: 56611  num_of_checkout_item:2

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: you just want number of counts in that condition.right

Comment: why the title is "delete row ..."?

Answer (score 1):

I assume "count checkout_item-s only which happened together with checkout" implies that the timestamp of `checkout_item` and `checkout` have to be the same for the `checkout_item` to count.

```
def count_items(group):
    if not "checkout" in group.action.values:
        return 0
    return (group.action == "checkout_item").sum()

>>> df.groupby(["user", "timestamp"]).apply(count_items).groupby("user").sum()
user
56610    3
56611    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
users = [56610, 56611]
print(len(df[(df.user.isin(users)) & (df.action == "checkout_item")]))
```

or per user:

```
for user in users:
    counts = len(df[(df.user == user) & (df.action == "checkout_item")])
    print(f"user: {user} num_of_checkout_item: {counts}")
```

Comment: I use this, but what if a user has checkout_accept? It will count checkout_item with checkout and checkout_item with checkout_accept both. But actually I want to count checkout_item if it is happend with checkout.

Comment: @KorosiGabor I am not sure I understand you correctly. Can you give more details or rephrase? What kind of other conditions do you want to add for counting?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about that but give this a try if you want to remove the specific row.

```
df = df.drop(df[(df.user == 56610)  & (df.action =='checkout_item')].index)

df = df.drop(df[(df.user == 56611)  & (df.action =='checkout_item')].index)
```